# Only paste last piece of code in column

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to this software and could really use a hand. I am using Ditta to store multiple items on a clipboard and have given them a shortcut. With this script I am trying to get it to paste all copied items at once, using a shortcut key. I have tested each block of code individually and it works. But when I try to run it together, it only runs the final block. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
Sub Data()
    ActiveCell.Select
    SendKeys "^4", True
    Application.Wait (2000)

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    SendKeys "^3", True
    Application.Wait (1000)

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    SendKeys "^2", True
    Application.Wait (1000)

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    SendKeys "^1", True
    Application.Wait (1000) 
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you really want to select the exact same content 3 times in a row?

Comment: No, ideally i want it to post each individual piece of data in a column.

Comment: e.g Name = A1, Email = B1 ect

Comment: @Stewbob where does he "*select the exact same content 3 times in a row*"? Didn't you see the `Offset(0, 1)`? The range moves 1 to the right on every selection. (ok he *could* omit the `Range("A1")` here but it still works with it.)

Comment: @Peh, I missed the offset.  The unneeded Range("A1") threw me off.

Comment: @JoeDavison Try a `DoEvents` after every `Select` line. Or if that doesn't work after every `SendKeys` line. Maybe you can then even omit these `Wait` lines. And as I said before `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select` should be enough.

Comment: Sorry if ive confused you guys, do you understand what the issue im having is, or should i try and explain again.

Comment: Thank you, can you please show me where you think tht should go, still learning

Comment: @JoeDavison As I said write a new line with the command `DoEvents` before evey line starting with `SendKeys` (or *after* them; not sure which one would really help).

Comment: That has not worked, it just brings back the same outcome,

Comment: I can see it move across all the columns, but it only pastes the final piece of data leaving the 3 columns to the left of it empty?

Comment: do you have any other ideas

Comment: @JoeDavison no idea what exactly the issue is, but how you used `.Wait` is not correct. Have a look at my answer to see how you could implement that as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where exactly the issue is, but it seems that it is all about waiting for Ditto to insert the values. Your code is just not waiting until the paste is done.

I wrote a workaround for that:

1. We have a loop now that runs from 4 to 1 counting backwards (this is to send the 4 keys. This is easier than having 4 times the same code.
2. The main idea is to clear the cell before we paste, and after the paste we wait until the cell is not empty anymore, which means the paste was successful. Note this is just a workaround to wait an amount of time until the paste is done.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub InsertData()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 4 To 1 Step -1                  'loop from 4 to 1 backwards
        ActiveCell.Clear                    'clear active cell (so we know it is empty for sure)
        SendKeys "^" & CStr(i), True        'send keys for paste

        'wait until active cell isn't empty anymore.
        'this means wait until paste is done
        Do While IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
            DoEvents    'give Excel some time to handle other events
        Loop

        'move over to the next cell
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

**Just a note to your original code**

Your waiting was wrong anyway `Application.Wait(2000)` does not what you expect it to do. The correct way would be:

```
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
```

To make it wait 2 seconds. The given time is not the *amount* of time to wait but the *absolute time until* the macro waits. For more see [Application.Wait Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-wait-method-excel).

Comment: This is great and i have clearly seen it work a few times, it does ocasionaly  only paste the first one or two. why would this be

Comment: @JoeDavison This might be when one of the 4 paste slots in Ditto is empty. Then this workaround won't work. Does it always happen with the same data? Are there 4 paste slots filled with data (not empty) in Ditto? Also make sure you don't click anywhere while the code is running. Can you tell if it is reproducible on any set of data within the 4 slots in Ditto or does it occasionally happen on the **same** 4 data?

Comment: I am copying multiple points of data from the web and ideally want to me able to move it to excel quicker. To answer you question yes all slots are filled and they all contain different data. Can you think of any quicker more efficient  ways?